# Unable to get property 'hide' of undefined or null reference

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, modalpopupextender

My javascript generates an error when I try to close a "ModalPopup" that is not open.
(Windows 7 / Visual Studio 2012 / asp.net c# css3 html5)
Here is my Javascript ModalPopup Page validator:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var $find= function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
};
   setInterval(closePopup,1000);


    function closePopup() {
      if (!Page_IsValid) {
         $find('mpeScheduleTask').hide();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Works fine if it's open, generates an error when not open...

Error:  0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'hide' of undefined or null reference

Comment: You might want to use a selector ( #,.) etc. if you are trying to use the jQuery find.

Comment: I am curious, what library is $find?

Comment: I have solved this issue, but to answer Pathachiever11's question, I added my $find function. Thanks to all -- this answer is so obvious to me now that I have come to understand JQuery thanks largely to Murach's "JavaScript and JQuery" book... it's from 2012, but a great, easy, quick read and it will explain it all in terms you can understand. (and no.. I have no affiliation... just appreciation for their hard work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for its existence first:

```
function closePopup() {
   if (!Page_IsValid) {
      var mPopup = $find('mpeScheduleTask');
      if (mPopup) mPopup.hide();
    }
}
```